# Is it possible to have a web url act as another?

Tags: http, https

I help run a college radio website and for our streaming service we used to use a webpage like: http://streaming.mysite.com

This site was acting a redirect (there may be a better word for this) for two different streaming sites e.g. http://streaming.one.mysite.com and http://streaming.two.mysite.com We would choose on the domain side which site was the currently active one.

The (main) streaming page acts in place as one of the two other sites. So whenever you went to http://streaming.mysite.com/listen it was really http://streaming.one.mysite.com/listen but it showed as http://streaming.mysite.com/listen

We recently upgraded to https via certbot + nginx and our previous approach now gives an invalid certificate when we bring the redirected site up.

Is our previous approach still possible? Is this due to how https/certifying works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `http://streaming.mysite.com/` is set up as a reverse proxy to `http://streaming.one.mysite.com` and `http://streaming.two.mysite.com`.

If the assumption is correct, just switching from http to https results in the reverse proxy presenting traffic from e.g. `http://streaming.one.mysite.com` to the client, including the SSL Certificate which doesn't match the servers name from client perspective now: Accessing `http://streaming.mysite.com/` but getting certificate of `http://streaming.one.mysite.com`.

You need to terminate the SSL connection at `http://streaming.mysite.com/` to present the client a valid certificate for `http://streaming.mysite.com/`. The reverse proxy then should be configured to load the data using https from `http://streaming.one.mysite.com` / `http://streaming.two.mysite.com`.